# how to make border around an image - libgdx?

Tags: android, libgdx

i have  a large image ,then i cut it into 9 equal small images. that is my code

```
Image pricer[][] = new Image[3][3];

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        pricer[i][j] = new Image(TextureRegion.split(bg, tile, tile)[i][j]);
        pricer[i][j].setSize(200, 200);
        pricer[i][j].setPosition((j*200),600-(i*200));
        stage.addActor(pricer[i][j]);       
    }
}
```

now, i want to create border for those images that i devide into small peace.many thanks for your help

Comment: You just draw a border around the position of each image. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a ShapeRenderer:

```
ShapeRenderer renderer = new ShapeRenderer();
renderer.begin(ShapeType.Line)
renderer.setColor(color);
renderer.rect(image.getImageX(), image.getImageY(), image.getImageWidth(), image.getImageHeight);
renderer.end();
```